# Excel Formula para formatar tabelas

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula

Existe alguma fórmula para encadear as cores de uma tabela?
Eu não quero o "normal" (p.e. vermelho|branco|vermelho). O que pretendo é sempre que o nome de determinada célula for igual, então o fundo é de cor A, quando o nome da célula for diferente então muda para a cor B, quando o nome voltar a mudar então a cor volta a ser a cor A e assim adiante.

Exemplo de tabela.

```
Teste    X    B   A    T   -> cor A
Teste    f    s   f    g   -> cor A
ALPHA    f    s   f    g   -> cor B
ALPHA    g    g   h    r   -> cor B
ALPHA    f    s   f    g   -> cor B
Beta     G    A   f    g   -> cor A
.......
```

O valor a comparar é da primeira coluna pelo valor da primeira coluna da lina anterior.

É possível?

Comment: Sim. Você pode fazer isso com código, mas só tera efeito em sua máquina, embora permitir que seu Excel execute códigos é perigoso.

Comment: E como faço? Podes dar um exemplo do codigo?

Comment: Acesse o menu Macros -> Gravar Macro -> Ok. Faça várias mudanças de estilo, cores, preenchimentos, etc. Volte no menu Macros -> Exibir Macros e veja o código que o Excel criou para você. Crie uma nova planilha,volte em Macros -> Exibir Macros. Selecione sua Macro e clique em Executar. Agora você pode aterar o código como quiser.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente eu uso a formatação condicional, vc pode selecionar apenas as celular e depois clicar na aba formatação condicional, ou selecionar o documento inteiro.

Depois de clicar em Formatação condicional escolha Realçar Regras das Células ai é só escolher quais são as condições para trocar as cores automaticamente de acordo com a palavra, se é maior que, menor que, igual a, etc....

Simples assim

Comment: Dessa maneira já consegui fazer mas queria tentar mais dinâmico, ou seja, a formula vai ver o valor da linha anterior para ver se é igual ou não, se for igual a cor mantém-se se for diferente muda.
A tabela tens os valores a comparar ordenados de forma alfabética.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Se ainda puder ajudar, e **se for possível criar uma coluna extra** onde terá o critério da formatação condicional, podes usar a fórmula abaixo:

```
=SE(A2=A1;D1;-(D1))
```

Fiz a fórmula na coluna D. Coloca a referência para a coluna onde ficar esta fórmula.

O valor da célula D1 deve diferente de 0 (coloquei 1, pra facilitar).

Já na formatação condicional, podes selecionar para "Usar uma fórmula para determinar quais células devem ser formatadas" e usar a fórmula abaixo:

```
=$D1=-1
```

Novamente, a referência à coluna "D" é conforme a coluna onde vai estar a fórmula.

O valor "-1" é por que coloquei valor 1 na célula D1.

Para não variar a referência em relação a coluna onde está a fórmula, coloca "$" antes do "D" ("$D").

E o intervalo deve começar na mesma linha da fórmula (no caso, linha 1). Se não, tem que contar a diferença entre a referência.

Espero ter ajudado.